# JPA hibernate insertion not locking

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, locking, insertion

We are using SpringFramework 3.2.12.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.6.FINAL against Oracle 11g.

We have a service managed by JPATransactionManager. The service accepts an id as primary key and creates a new entity with the id, saves it, makes an external call, then updates the entity. Under multi-thread testing with the same id, I am expecting all other threads are blocking after the first thread has done the insertion and making external call, however it is not the case. The service is annotated with  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly=false), and the two save calls are made via JpaRepository. Below is my spring configuration.

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"></property>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"></property>
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="abstractEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
</bean>
<bean id="myEntityManagerFactory" parent="abstractEntityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="PackagesToScan" value="test.schema" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="test.dao"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="myEntityManagerFactory"></jpa:repositories>
```

Appreciate comments and help!

Comment: From what I understood I guess you need to use LockMode to lock the record when its first being processed.

Comment: Thanks Addullah, but shouldn't insertion acquires write lock itself? I do have @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) on the save method of the repository, however, my understanding is that PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock is only for existing record for update.

Comment: You don't need a lock while insertion. I think you need to lock the record after save so that once you get the external response back you can update it and then process the next request.

Comment: Are you suggesting to commit the insertion first? In my case, the transaction has not commit after insertion, why is it not blocking?

Comment: Why would it block ? The lock you specified will lock the row which already exists but in your case you have not persisted the record.

Comment: If I start two SquirrelSQL sessions both with autocommit turned off. Both executing insertion query, the second will block until the first commits. Seems hibernate behaves differently.